# css background image clip

Tags: css, background-image, background-position

Im setting my image src in php and controlling the styling in css. I have an image sprite but no matter what I do the image does not seem to clip to the area I want. Im just getting the whole image appear dispite my background-size being set to 24 by 24px.

Note that the img src has to stay in the HTML rather than moving to a bg-image in the css :)

A jsfiddle can be seen here
jsfiddle.net/s6UnV

Any ideas?

```
#swap li img {
    background-position: 0 0px;
    background-size: 24px 24px;
    display: block;
    text-indent: -10000px;
    -webkit-transition: background-position .6s;
    -moz-transition: background-position .6s;
    -o-transition: background-position .6s;
    -ms-transition: background-position .6s;
    transition: background-position .6s;
}

#swap li img:hover {
   background-position: 0 -24px;
}
```

Comment: Can you set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s6UnV/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use the tag img for sprites, you should use a div with a background-image to the one you would like to add the sprite effects.

I updated your jsFiddle here [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s6UnV/5/)

What i did was the following

Changed the Html to

```
<ul id="swap">
  <li>
    <a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">
       <div class="fb-sprite" style=" background-image:url('http://rldesign.net/Joomla3/modules/mod_social_css3/assets/glyph/facebook_hover.png')">
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And added the fb-sprite class style to the css

```
.fb-sprite{
    width:24px;
    height:24px;
    background-position: 0 0px;
    background-size: 24px 48px;
    display: block;
    -webkit-transition: background-position .6s;
    -moz-transition: background-position .6s;
    -o-transition: background-position .6s;
    -ms-transition: background-position .6s;
    transition: background-position .6s;
    }

.fb-sprite:hover{
   background-position: 0 -24px;
    }
```

Hope it helps

ps: you can also use the opacity effect on this one so the facebook logo doesn't disappear
out of the blue, just a suggestion.

Cheers.

EDIT: Now you can change the url of the img programtically and the style would work. Also Updated the jsFiddle

Comment: Unfortunantly that solution will not work for me as I am programtically selecting the img, that was why it was written in the html rather than the CSS. But thank you anyway, any other suggestions?

Comment: Oh i get it!! You could do simply <div class="fb-sprite" style="background-image:url('your selector')" > </div> and remove the background-image part form css.

Comment: @rowanwins I'm not quite sure what you mean by "I am programtically selecting the img" but maby you should rethink your approach?

Comment: @jurgemaister I've created a variable in php that returns an img url (eg www.google.com/logo.png). Because that needs to be changable I can't write it into the css. However I'd like to the css styling to be the same irrespective of the image that is chosen, hence the approach, although I am a rookie so if there's a better way Im open to it :)

Comment: @LucasLazaro awesome dude, thanks so much, that updated solution has done the trick!